How can I connect all points in a graph with a line given that there are some missing ("NA) values?
I have two dependent variables that I am plotting with respect to my independent variable. One of the dependent variable has several missing values. Here's the data
dataset "test"



X
A
B




0.0
50
160


1.0
45
145


1.5
42



2.0
39
130


2.5
36
126


3.0
35



3.5
31



4.0
28



4.5
25
108


5.0
22
103


5.5
20
99


6.0
19
92



When I try to connect the points on the line with geom_line() function, it only connects the points that are consecutive. If there is a gap in data between (shown in the table), then ggplot will not draw a line.
  test %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X))+
  geom_line(aes(y=A))+
  geom_line(aes(y=B), color = "blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "A", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,name = "B",
                                         breaks = seq(0,200,10),
                                         guide = "axis_minor"),
                     breaks = seq(0,200,10),
                     guide = "prism_minor")


I am looking to form a continuous line by connected the gaps in the Blue line. Any help would be highly appreciated.

You can also make this easier with reshaping your data: test %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-X) %>% dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) %>% ggplot() + aes(X, value, color=name)  + geom_line()
